# Dynamic section name in wicked_pdf header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

In Wicked_pdf I have several sections. Each section is starts a new page and is started by a header like so:

```
<h2 class="section" style="color: #0050b2;font: arial, sans-serif;font-size: 17;">Application details</h2>
```

In my header I would like to display the section name on the first and all subsequent pages that belong to this section. I know that this would be Javascript / jQuery, but my skills in this area are woefully inadequate.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this code snippet below, taken from [WickedPDF Readme](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#page-numbering):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function number_pages() {
        var vars={};
        var x=document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
        for(var i in x) {var z=x[i].split('=',2);vars[z[0]] = unescape(z[1]);}
        var x=['frompage','topage','page','webpage','section','subsection','subsubsection'];
        for(var i in x) {
          var y = document.getElementsByClassName(x[i]);
          for(var j=0; j<y.length; ++j) y[j].textContent = vars[x[i]];
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="number_pages()">
    Page <span class="page"></span> of <span class="topage"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Especially this line:

```
var x=['frompage','topage','page','webpage','section','subsection','subsubsection'];
```

These are special parameters made available on each PDF pages, accessible via `document.location.search`. For your case, luckily `subsection` contains the text content of  element in your PDF pages.

Now, to achieve the dynamic header, in your controller you need to specify the `:header`, and point it to an erb file which contains:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function subst() {
        var vars={};
        var x=document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
        for(var i in x) {var z=x[i].split('=',2);vars[z[0]] = unescape(z[1]);}

        document.getElementById('dynamic-header').innerHTML = vars['section'];
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="subst()">
    <h2 id="dynamic-header">Replace me!</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

The header will be replaced by the  element found inside your PDF page. This also solves your dynamic requirement, because `vars['section']` will contain the same content until it finds another  with different content. Please note that I haven't tested the code above, but I hope you get the idea.